# Upgrade python version in GCP Composer

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

We have a GCP composer with Python version 3. I would like to update the version to Python 3.9 but I am unable to find the edit option to make this change in my composer. Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot but there is a workaround.

- You cannot because Cloud Composer uses docker images that bundle Airflow releases with Python, Python libraries and other common binaries. You can only upgrade to newer composer images version. And the last version have python 3.8.6 at the moment of writing. (the complete images list is [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/versioning/composer-versions#images)).
- The workaround to use python 3.9 in your task(s) is to use KubernetesPodOperator with an image of your choice. You can find [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-kubernetes-pod-operator) more details on how you can work with KubernetesPodOperator.